# Como colocar una alerta de boostrap en ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trabajo en un proyecto en C#, el cual requiero que una alerta me salga como este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual se obtiene mediante el siguiente código:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.
  </div>
```

lo quiero sustituir por este tipo de alerta:

```
        {
            LabelError.Visible = true;
            LabelError.Text = "usuario o contraseña invalido !!";
        }
```

Podrían ayudarme un poco.

Comment: Que tipo de control ASP.NET es `LabelError`?. indícalo en la pregunta por favor,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes añadirle en los atributos del control la clase css (`class`) de Bootstrap:

```
LabelError.Visible = true;
LabelError.InnerHtml = "usuario o contraseña invalido !!";
LabelError.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-danger");
```

**Nota**: Todo esto, siempre y cuando el control ASP.NET `LabelError` sea del tipo **`<div />`**:

```
var LabelError = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

Comment: Fue de gran ayuda tu comentario no fue necesario especificar el (div) ya con la clase hizo todo el trabajo.(Y)